# Tomcat giving 404 error with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have been building a Spring webapp from [this website](http://dtr-trading.blogspot.com/2014/02/spring-mvc-4-and-hibernate-4.html). When I run the tutorial code, the app runs perfectly. However, when I run my adapted version of the code, I get the following error:

[image]

I have no idea why this is occurring; I've effectively copy-and-pasted the whole code base, just changing data to Campaign rather than Strategy.

Here is my configuration class:

```
package com.bridge.campaignspring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.bridge.campaignspring")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

I cannot access any created .jsp's that I've created. I only see the 404 error. If any more code is needed to resolve this, please ask; I can post whatever it necessary.

**EDIT:** Here is my CampaignController class:

```
package com.bridge.campaignspring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.bridge.campaignspring.model.Campaign;
import com.bridge.campaignspring.service.CampaignService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/campaign")
public class CampaignController {

    @Autowired
    private CampaignService campaignService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addCampaignPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("campaign-add");
        modelAndView.addObject("campaign", new Campaign());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingCampaign(@ModelAttribute Campaign campaign) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        campaignService.addCampaign(campaign);
        String message = "Campaign was added sucessfully";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/list")
    public ModelAndView listOfCampaigns() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("campaign-list");
        List<Campaign> campaigns = campaignService.getCampaigns();
        modelAndView.addObject("campaigns", campaigns);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editCampaignPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("campaign-edit");
        Campaign campaign = campaignService.getCampaign(id);
        modelAndView.addObject("campaign", campaign);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editingCampaign(@ModelAttribute Campaign campaign, @PathVariable Integer id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        campaignService.updateCampaign(campaign);
        String message = "Campaign edited successfully";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteCampaign(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        campaignService.deleteCampaign(id);
        String message = "Campaign deleted successfully";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your `web.xml`?

Comment: Per the tutorial, I do not have a web.xml file.

Comment: Have you also controllers mentioned in blog post?

Comment: @lkrnac yes I have the Controllers as outlined in the tutorial. I will edit OP to reflect my changes.

Comment: Where did you get `/CampaignSpringEx02` from?

Comment: @lkrnac `CampaignSpringEx02` is the project that I have created to mirror the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what happened, but it might have been something in my Tomcat configuration. I deleted the server then re-added it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You URL should contain `/campaign/add`, ...

URLs are defined by annotation attributes in `@RequestMapping`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/campaign")
public class CampaignController {

    @Autowired
    private CampaignService campaignService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addCampaignPage() {
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I have the Controller set up the way you posted. When I try to go to `/CampaignSpringEx02/campaign/add`, I get a 404 error.

Comment: `http://localhost/campaign/add.html` returns 404 "requested resource not available".